# In an ADC what are the units of resolution called?

Tags: adc, analog

I have a signal whose full scale output on the 12bit ADC is 4095. If I reduce the signal so I see the output number is (say) 4000 the output has decreased by 95. But 95 what? What are those divisions called? It is clearly (?) not bits.

Comment: Counts? Bits? Usually, in the DMM world, it is called counts.

Comment: Or 95 "steps" or maybe "levels"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Speaking as an applications engineer at a company that makes ADC chips... the unit is called `LSB` (least significant bit), so in your example the ADC output code would be 4000 LSB. (A commenter notes that this could also be called `Counts`; this would also make sense for dual-slope ADC.)

This is normally only interesting when reading the ADC's datasheet, where there's usually a specified level of accuracy for INL (Integral Non-Linearity) / DNL (Differential Non-Linearity) / offset error / gain error. See for example the datasheet for [MAX11300](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX11300.pdf#page=3),  the ADC Electrical Specifications. *(Disclosure: I am a Maxim applications engineer, and this is one of the products I support.)* Maxim gives the INL/DNL units as LSB.

Note this isn't a physical unit, it's just a name for the raw count value returned by the ADC. There doesn't seem to be a real consensus as to what to call this raw ADC code unit. Typically an application would use some linear mapping (and possibly calibration values) to convert the ADC LSB code into a meaningful physical unit. For example, 4000 LSB * 5.00 Volts / 4096 LSB = 4.88 Volts.

When I write software to do this kind of conversion, I usually name the raw ADC value something like `ADC_Code` and the voltage as `ADC_Voltage`. I would be concerned that in the context of software, "count" could be mis-interpreted as an iteration count (which is valid inside a DVM or other dual-slope ADC that actually counts how long it takes to charge/discharge a capacitor).

Comment: I rather like LSBs Unless someone has a better suggestion I will probably stick with that in the documentation

Comment: Shouldn't it be 4000 LSB * 5.00 Volts / 4095 LSB = 4.88 Volts? I know you'd typically switch to a power of 2 as division is easier (faster) for power of 2, but it's a source of error? (more apparent in low resolution ADCs)

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps calling the unit as LSBs might be confusing in some circumstances due to least significant bit referring to, well, the least significant bit of a byte.

Comment: +1 The unit is definitely LSBs. It is well understood and nearly universal across ADC vendors. Often sensitivity will be expressed in LSBs per Unit.

Comment: @Arsenal: That depends on whether 0 and 5V are the center or outside edges of the bins corresponding to 0 and 4095.  Different ADCs vary in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) article on ADCs refers to these amounts as "levels".

> The values are usually stored electronically in binary form, so the resolution is usually expressed in bits. In consequence, the number of discrete values available, or "**levels**", is assumed to be a power of two. For example, an ADC with a resolution of 8 bits can encode an analog input to one in 256 different levels, since 2^8 = 256. The values can represent the ranges from 0 to 255 (i.e. unsigned integer) or from −128 to 127 (i.e. signed integer), depending on the application.

Comment: I don't think this is right. The level is the value, not the unit of the value. "Level" is to the wanted word as "power" is to "watt".

Comment: @KevinReid Yes but there is no unit on a unitless value.  Levels or steps is typical.

Comment: Whether it is unitless formally is arguable, but the OP is asking for a word that has the syntactic role of a unit, which this isn't. A level is a value, OP wants the name of the smallest _difference between_ levels.