# What is LSB "unit"?

Tags: dac

In a binary number, the LSB is the least significant bit (the MSB is the most significant bit). I do know that as well as binary scheme.

A DAC is a system that transforms a digital number (expressed in binary format) to an analogic number. I do know about this.

What is meaning of expressing units of "[LSB]" for a DAC. That is : what is meaning that a given number is expressed in terms of "LSB"? I would think that the unit is just "bit". So why saying [LSB]? What is the meaning?

[image]

Comment: If you have a 10 bit DAC and Vref is 5V then the LBS is 5V/1024 = 4.88mV

Comment: Looks like a 12bit DAC scale with different resolutions / bit (lsb) vs byte LSB so 4096 lsb’s are either 0.5V or 1.0V full scale (FS)

Comment: @G36. Sure, thank you. But still, why do we express DAC in units of LSB, why don't we express it in unit of *bit* ?

Comment: @Tony Stewart EE75 : sorry, your point seems extremely important. Could you clarify a bit what you mean ?

Comment: No pun intended but when ambiguous (a bit) , bits are b and bytes are B, otherwise may use LSB for bits when not ambiguous. Then analog references determine resolution for full scale

Comment: For DAC LSB is the smallest increment/decrement we can get at the output

Comment: sorry, but still the "bit" is the smallest increment/decrement for the output. So why do we write [LSB] instead of [bit] ?

Comment: Within a word each bit has a different value, with the most significant bit being valued at 2^(word_length-1) times larger than the least significant bit.  Saying least significant bit makes it explicit which you are referring to, although typically the meaning can be inferred from context so people would understand if you just said "bit".

Comment: @user1850479 : thank you. Your explanation is the key one. Maybe put it in the official answer to get the official thanks.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/188922/35022

Comment: Nothing is explained there in this "related link" about my specific question : they assume that people understand why the unit of LSB is chosen. So there is no direct relationship. (and I read it before asking the question)

Answer (score 1):

The diagram of a DAC is not a "straight line", but a staircase. Thus, the weight of "LSB" is the height of a step. It is also, in binary, the value of the least significant bit.

The "precision" (may be linearity) of a DAC is also expressed in some LSB bits. Say for exemple 1/2 LSB. The monotonocity of the DAC is also expressed in this unit, example: 2 LSB (bad converter). The essential problem is that the height of each step is exactly the same, which may be difficult to achieve.

The DACs are also specified some times with 1/4 LSB, more precise than needed.

Comment: Sure, still the "bit" is the height of the a step. So why do we write [LSB] instead of "[bit]" ?

Comment: I think this is an "abuse" of language. LSB used for a DAC is the (average) height of a staircase or whether it is in the figure. And it is assumed that all the stairs have the same height. In the case of the use of the term "bit", reference is made to a binary number. it is therefore the smallest increase value of a number which is 1. By extension, we also speak of the least significant bit (b0).

Comment: Because flipping the least significant bit changes the signal by a step height but flipping any other bit changes it by more.

Comment: thanks all. It is clear to me now.